Why isn't the "job_id" attribute found in Cups printer?
We are implementing a function to print PDF by linking CUPS source using JNI in Android.
Tests were conducted on two printers.

Samsung SL-C1404W -> Printed normally
Epson L6290 -> 0x400(client-bad-request)

After taking a picture of the code loading, I think the client-bad-request error occurs because job_id in getJobId() is null and job_id is -1.
job_id = getJobId(monitor->http, monitor->http_resource,
                                          monitor->printer_uri, &new_state,
                                          monitor->requesting_user);
LOGE("1.job_id = %d", job_id); ///1.job_id = -1

getJob() impl
int getJobId(http_t *http,
              char *http_resource,
              char *printer_uri,        /* I - URI buffer */
              job_state_dyn_t *job_state_dyn,
              const char *requesting_user) {
    int job_id = -1;
    // Requested print job attributes
    static const char *jattrs[] = {"job-id"};
    ipp_t *request = NULL;  /* IPP request object */
    ipp_t *response = NULL; /* IPP response object */

    request = ippNewRequest(IPP_GET_JOBS);

    LOGE("getJobId: http_resource => %s", http_resource); //getJobId: http_resource => /ipp/print
    LOGE("getJobId: printer_uri => %s", printer_uri);  //getJobId: printer_uri => ipp://printer_id_addr/ipp/print
    LOGE("getJobId: requesting_user => %s", requesting_user);

    if (request != NULL) { //request not null
        ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_URI, "printer-uri", NULL, printer_uri);
        ippAddBoolean(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, "my-jobs", 1);
        ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_NAME, "requesting-user-name",
                     NULL, requesting_user);
        ippAddStrings(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_KEYWORD, "requested-attributes",
                      sizeof(jattrs) / sizeof(jattrs[0]), NULL, jattrs);

        if ((response = ipp_doCupsRequest(http, request, http_resource, printer_uri)) == NULL) {
            job_state_dyn->job_state = IPP_JOB_STATE_UNABLE_TO_CONNECT;
            job_state_dyn->job_state_reasons[0] = IPP_JOB_STATE_REASON_UNABLE_TO_CONNECT;
        } else {

            ipp_attribute_t *attr = ippFindAttribute(response, "job-id", IPP_TAG_INTEGER); //attr = NULL (not find "job_id" attr)
            if (attr != NULL) { 
                LOGE("getJobId() attr->integer : %d", attr->values[0].integer);
                job_id = ippGetInteger(attr, 0); 
                LOGE("getJobId(): attr != NULL -> %d", job_id);
            }
            else LOGE("getJobId() attr is NULL");
            LOGE("getJobId() job_id is %d", job_id);
        }
    }

    if (request != NULL) ippDelete(request);
    if (response != NULL) ippDelete(response);

    ///LOG
    LOGE("getJobId() returning job-id: %d", job_id); ///getJobId() returning job-id :-1
    return job_id;
}

Are you just not finding the "job_id" attribute for your specific printer?
